# A program returns 'undefined' after returning correct values. (Rock Paper Scissors game)

Tags: javascript

I wrote this program and it behaves the way I planned and returns correct results.
Except, it also returns 'undefined' too, after displaying game results in the console.

I searched and read similar posts about 'function returning undefined' and still don't fully get the concept behind.

From which function am I getting 'undefined' in my code? why and how to fix it?

```
const options = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor']

let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

function computerPlay() {
    // Randomly choose the computer's option from the options array.
    let computerChoice = 
        options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
  return computerChoice;
}

function capitalizeUserInput(playerInput) {
    // Turn user input to a capitalized string.
    playerInput = playerInput[0].toUpperCase()
    + playerInput.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    return playerInput;
}

function playRound(comSelect, playerSelect) {
    // Create a variable to return the result.
    let result;

    // If result is tie, return draw.
    if (comSelect == playerSelect) {
        return result = "draw";
    // If User wins, increment the user score and return win.
    } else if (comSelect == 'Rock' && playerSelect == 'Paper' ||
               comSelect == 'Paper' && playerSelect == 'Scissor' ||
               comSelect == 'Scissor' && playerSelect == 'Rock') {
        playerScore += 1;
        return result = "win"; 
    // If Computer wins, increment the computer score and return lose.           
    } else {
        computerScore += 1;
        return result = "lose";
    }
}

function game(totalRound = 5) { 
    let gamePlayed = 0;
    while (gamePlayed < totalRound) {
        let player = prompt('Rock, paper or scissor?!')
        let computer = computerPlay();

        player = capitalizeUserInput(player);
        result = playRound(computer,player);

        if (result == 'win') {
            console.log(`${player} beats ${computer}, you won.`);
        } else if (result == 'lose') {
            console.log(`${computer} beats ${player}, you lost.`);
        } else {
            console.log('Draw!');
        }
        gamePlayed ++;
    }
    return displayGameResult(computerScore, playerScore);
}


function displayGameResult(computerScore, playerScore) {
    if (computerScore > playerScore) {
        console.log(`${computerScore}:${playerScore} You lost.`);
    } else if (playerScore > computerScore) {
        console.log(`${computerScore}:${playerScore} You won.`);
    } else {
        console.log(`${computerScore}:${playerScore} Record Tie!`);
    }
}


console.log(game(5));
```

Comment: `displayGameResult` doesn’t return anything.

Comment: How many `console.log` statements do you have? What do you expect each to output and why?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thank you. After reading other answers I understood now.

Comment: @deceze Except the last `console.log(game(5));`, all the rest of `console.log` statements were intended to display how the game is going, as the program is only to be played in the console at the moment. Definitely there was no need to log the last one, but just call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling `console.log(game(5));`, `game()` is doing `return displayGameResult(computerScore, playerScore);`, but the problem is that `displayGameResult()` is not returning anything, so it returns `undefined`.

You can fix this by simply changing `console.log(game(5));` to just `game(5)` and changing `return displayGameResult(computerScore, playerScore);` to `displayGameResult(computerScore, playerScore);` because these functions are not returning anything important and using their `console.log()` functions independently to console the result of the game would be better.

Comment: Thank you @Zayaan for the answer. So I was expecting a function, that is not supposed to return anything, to return something. Now I understood. I am very new to JS and ㅣittle things like this get confusing still.

Answer (score 1):

you are loggin the return of the function game() by doing this `console.log(game(5));`
but the function game is returning `displayGameResult(computerScore, playerScore)` and this function doesn't return anything and so you are logging undefined;

Just try to add `return "not undefined ;) :P";` at the end of the displayGameResult function and you will not have undefined anymore